# Функция pthread_create() не выполняет рутину в потоке

Tags: c, unix, qnx

Есть функция, обрабатывающая файл. Обработка состоит в сортировке чисел из этого файла и записи результата поверх старых данных. В случае, когда вызываю эту функцию сам, всё хорошо работает, но когда создаю поток с помощью pthread_create(), в котором она должна выполняться, содержимое файла не меняется. Причём pthread_create() возвращает 0, т.е. отрабатывает нормально. Видимо, не до конца понимаю, как работает эта функция. Прошу объяснить, что я делаю не так.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>


    void* selectSort();


    int main()
    {
        pthread_create(NULL, NULL, selectSort, NULL);

        return 0;
    }


    void* selectSort()
    {
        int i, j, n, min_ind, buff, *A;
        FILE* File;

        File = fopen("f.txt", "r");
        fscanf(File, "%d", &n);
        A = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fscanf(File, "%d", &A[i]);
        }
        fclose(File);

        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            min_ind = j;
            for (i = j + 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (A[i] < A[min_ind])
                    min_ind = i;
            }
            buff = A[min_ind];
            A[min_ind] = A[j];
            A[j] = buff;
        }

        File = fopen("f.txt", "w");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fprintf(File, "%d\n", A[i]);
        }
        fclose(File);
    }
```

Comment: Как только заканчивает работу функция `main()`, Ваш поток благополучно тоже заканчивается не успев ничего сделать. Вы должны дождаться в основном потоке (в `main()`), пока запущенный поток не завершит работу. Для этого, можно воспользоваться функцией `pthread_join()` (ага, в `main()` после запуска потока), но Вы должны передать ей дескриптор потока (типа `pthread_t`), которого Вы не сделали. Как-то так.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я напрочь забыл про это. Спасибо за напоминание.)